# File upload with .net core minimal API, Swagger not showing parameter name

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I've created .net core minimal API to upload file using .net 7, Swashbuckle 6.5.
API working without Swagger and tested with Postman.

Adding OpenAPI/Swagger support with Swashbuckle, it generates test page but file upload parameter name it doesn't show in Swagger and trying to upload file without name cause following error.

The issue is reported in Swashbuckle GitHub issue tracker.
[https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2625](https://stackoverflow.com)

Is there any workaround for it

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Required parameter "IFormFile file" was not provided from form file.`

[image: Swagger screen]

[image]

```
app.MapPost("/ReadPDF", async (IFormFile file) =>
{
    string tempfile = CreateTempfilePath();
    using var stream = File.OpenWrite(tempfile);

    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    
    stream.Close();

    StringBuilder sbPDFText=new StringBuilder();
    

    return Text.ToString();

})
    .WithName("ReadPDF")
.WithOpenApi(operation => new(operation)
{

    Summary = "Reads text from PDF",
    Description = "This API returns all text in PDF document"
});
;
```

I already trying solution mentioned on the issue GitHub page as workaround but couldn't figure out.
[https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47692](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

By removing

> .WithOpenApiOptions

methods, problem is fixed and it's showing parameter name and works with Swagger UI.

[image]